# wrong camera rotation on flutter

Tags: flutter

when the camera after taking a picture, the position of the picture becomes wrong and not straight, here's the code I made

```
Future pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
try {
  final image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
  if(image == null) return;

  final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
  date = DateTime.now().toString();
  print(imageTemporary);
  
  setState(() {
    this.image = imageTemporary;
    this.date = date;
  });
  
  
} on PlatformException catch(e) {
  print('failed to pick image');
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it’s a bug in the library have you tried on physical device ? If still the issue persists then you can use this workaround :

```
Future<File> rotateAndCompressAndSaveImage(File image) async {
    int rotate = 0;
    List<int> imageBytes = await image.readAsBytes();
    Map<String, IfdTag> exifData = await readExifFromBytes(imageBytes);

    if (exifData != null &&
        exifData.isNotEmpty &&
        exifData.containsKey("Image Orientation")) {
      IfdTag orientation = exifData["Image Orientation"];
      int orientationValue = orientation.values[0];

      if (orientationValue == 3) {
        rotate = 180;
      }

      if (orientationValue == 6) {
        rotate = -90;
      }

      if (orientationValue == 8) {
        rotate = 90;
      }
    }

    List<int> result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(imageBytes,
        quality: 100, rotate: rotate);

    await image.writeAsBytes(result);

    return image;
  }
```